# How do I actually use OpenGL in Qt 5?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt5

Simply put, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to actually make use of things like `QOpenGLWidget` or `QOpenGLWindow` or anything. I want to have the rendering I do be a child widget of a window in a MDI, but nothing works.

Here's the code I have currently set up for the widget (at least, just the parts involving OpenGL):

```
Viewport::Viewport(QWidget * parent) : QOpenGLWidget(parent) { }

void Viewport::initializeGL() {
    initializeOpenGLFunctions();
}

void Viewport::paintGL() {
    // first, clear the screen
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}
```

And here's how I use the widget:

```
vp = new Viewport;
vp->resize(QSize(320,240));
hbox->addWidget(vp);
```

And the result is that I see nothing. I just see a tiny sliver of empty space next to the other widget in the window, but that's it. No black screen like I try to clear with, not even a 320x240-sized empty space.

Like I said, I've been unable to do this in any of the ways I could find, and it's really frustrating. Am I missing something obvious? There's very little documentation as-is, so it's hard to tell if I am, or if there's some weird corner case I'm running into. (For example, none of the documentation I find uses `QOpenGLWidget` as part of a larger widget; is that because it *can't* be, or because all the examples I can find are just lazy about using the widget as its own top-level window?)

Answer (score 1):

After some more fiddling around, it turns out my issue was apparently caused by the other object in the window (a `QListView`) by default taking up as much space as possible, making the OpenGL widget disappear since it doesn't have a minimum size.

In other words, the problem is fixed by either changing the `QListView` to have a `QSizePolicy::Preferred` sizing policy (since resizing the window will now let you see the OpenGL widget), or by giving the OpenGL widget a minimum or fixed size.

(As an aside, I really wish this could've been more obvious than just stumbling upon it by chance.)

Comment: it will be obvious next time :)

Comment: I know this is rather old, but fwiw, you can avoid problems like this if you place the widgets in designer rather than constructing them on the fly, so you can see what you're doing. The way to do this with custom widgets (like your `QOpenGLWidget`-derived ones, which are themselves derived from `QWidget`) is to place a placeholder `QWidget` on your form in designer as usual, then right click it and select "Promote To...". Then you set it to your new custom widget class there, and it will all magically work. Check out http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-custom-widgets.html.